# SSL error in python when submit a message to a pubsub topic

Tags: python, ssl, google-cloud-pubsub

Good Morning. I set up a python script that takes data from a camera and periodically sends Google's pubsub an alert message for a topic.

implemented the google pip install python lib google-cloud-pubsub and made the following script:

```
import cv2
import socket
import multiprocessing
from threading import Thread
import base64
import time
import json
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
import os
import sys
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/media/nand/google_pubsub_credencials.json"


class Data9:
    def __init__(self):
        self.topic_name = "production_aiplate"
        self.project_id = "hopeful-keep-247221"
        self.publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
        self.topic_path = self.publisher.topic_path(self.project_id, self.topic_name)
        self.sendData9()

    def sendData9(self):
        data = {'type':'data9'}
                    
        future = self.publisher.publish(self.topic_path, data=json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8'), type="data9")
        print(future.result())


data9 = Data9()
while True:
    data9.sendData9()
    time.sleep(5)
```

it generates the following error periodically and the code stops:
[image]

I already searched the google groups for ssl documentation, I implemented try: and except: to save the data in a queue and send it again later, but even then the cod lock.

```
E0724 16:58:39.759270274   15043 ssl_transport_security.cc:504] Corruption detected.
E0724 16:58:39.759681543   15043 ssl_transport_security.cc:480] error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT
E0724 16:58:39.759744468   15043 ssl_transport_security.cc:480] error:1000008b:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC
E0724 16:58:39.759778319   15043 secure_endpoint.cc:208]     Decryption error: TSI_DATA_CORRUPTED
49 44.0
49 44.0
E0724 16:58:40.148543757   15043 ssl_transport_security.cc:531] SSL_write failed with error SSL_ERROR_SSL.
```

Comment: Always add your error trace as text rather than images. It makes it easy to debug the problem.

Comment: sorry i will try to copy the error

Comment: Really does seem hard to debug. Some of the solutions that I found was to try and disable any `Anti-Virus` that you may be running and of course the good old try and upgrade all packages to the latest version. This was the only related [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/issues/1772) i was able to locate, it doesnt help much but may be you can take a read. Also try to upgrade to the latest version of python

Comment: im under linux all updated last version os raspibian buster

Comment: well in that case, i suppose you should consider raising an issue for the package on github. This is the only way for you to get clear reasons on whats going wrong.

Comment: i walready did that but i didint any responses